# Intel vaapi error: can't connect to X server

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, driver, intel, vaapi

I am using an EC2 with Ubuntu 18.04, CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz, and a Nvidia Tesla T4. It seems `vainfo` reports a problematic setup:

```
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

My goal is to use vaapi accelerated HW decoding with gstreamer in Python.

`lspci | grep VGA` returns:

```
00:01.3 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Device 1111
```

Note:

- I installed on the EC2 the Nvidia drivers (not sure if they could interfere with Intel's graphic card)
- I also installed OpenVINO
- I was following this guide http://lifestyletransfer.com/how-to-install-gstreamer-vaapi-plugins-on-ubuntu/ for the setup and I got stuck at the point when I run `vaapi`

How can I fix this?

Comment: VAAPI only works with Intel iGPU, not NVidia or whatever server motherboard graphics exist.  For example on my Skylake (i7-6700k) desktop "VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)".  (The device numbers from `lspci -n` are `00:02.0 0300: 8086:1912 (rev 06)`.)  It works with VAAPI for accelerated video playback, for example, with `mpv -vo vaapi foo.mp4`

Comment: For NVidia, you want `vdpau`, but IDK if NVidia Tesla cards have the video-decode fixed-function hardware.  You might want to ask that as a separate question (or maybe edit this one to replace it)

Comment: https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%208259CL.html says that Xeon doesn't have integrated graphics.  (I think from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Cascade_Lake-based_Xeon_microprocessors that no Cascade-Lake Xeon has integrated graphics.)

Comment: Actually, this isn't really a programming question, probably belongs on https://serverfault.com/ since it's about configuring / installing software for cloud-hosting instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU does not have Intel integrated graphic card.